# why is glyphicon shopping cart facing left - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm just wondering why the glyphicon shopping cart facing left in bootstrap. Any idea how to make it face to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why it's facing left however you could use the following CSS:

```
.icon-flipped {
transform: scaleX(-1);
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Then in the HTML: `<i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-flipped"></i>`

Though an easier method would be to use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) and take advantage of the rotate notation for any icons you want to change the direction of.

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-rotate-180"></i>
```

**Though as a note the Shopping Cart in Font Awesome actually faces right.**